# glut openGL making a cube from a generated model in blender

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, glut, blender

im trying to make a cube that i modeled in blender and exported as a c header file.Iv made a cube before but im planning to make something more complicated and was thing making the actual model in blender may help me save lots of time. The header file that was generated is :

```
#ifndef _BLENDER_EXPORT_H_
#define _BLENDER_EXPORT_H_

#define OBJECTS_COUNT 1
#define CUBE 0
/***************************************
 *          local transformations
 ***************************************/

float transformations[][16]={
    {1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f},
 };
/***************************************
 *  faces count for each mesh
 ***************************************/
unsigned int faces_count[]={12};

/***************************************
 *  vertices count for each mesh
 ***************************************/
unsigned int vertex_count[]={26};

/***************************************
 *  offset tables for each mesh
 ***************************************/
unsigned int vertex_offset_table []={
    0,
};
unsigned int indices_offset_table []={
    0,
};
/***************************************
 *  vertices definition
 ***************************************/

struct vertex_struct {
    float x,y,z;
    float nx,ny,nz;
    float u,v;
};
struct vertex_struct vertices[]={
    /* CUBE: 26 vertices */
    {1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.375624f, 0.500625f},
    {1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.500624f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.749375f},
    {1.000000f, 0.999999f, 1.000000f, -0.000000f, -0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.251875f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, -0.000000f, -0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.375624f, 0.003126f},
    {0.999999f, -1.000001f, 1.000000f, -0.000000f, -0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.624374f, 0.251874f},
    {1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.375624f, 0.500625f},
    {1.000000f, 0.999999f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.251875f},
    {1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.500624f},
    {1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -0.000000f, -1.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.873126f, 0.749375f},
    {0.999999f, -1.000001f, 1.000000f, -0.000000f, -1.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.873126f, 0.998126f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -0.000000f, -1.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.998126f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.998126f},
    {1.000000f, 0.999999f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.126874f, 0.998126f},
    {1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.126874f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.624373f, 0.003126f},
    {1.000000f, 0.999999f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, -0.000001f, 0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.251875f},
    {0.999999f, -1.000001f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, -0.000001f, 0.000000f, 0.624374f, 0.251874f},
    {1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, -0.000001f, 0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.500624f},
    {-1.000000f, -1.000000f, 1.000000f, -0.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.624375f, 0.998126f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, -1.000000f, -1.000000f, 0.000000f, -0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.749375f},
    {-1.000000f, 1.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f, 0.000000f, 0.375625f, 0.998126f},
};

#define INX_TYPE GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
unsigned short indexes[]={
/* CUBE 12 faces */
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 0, 2, 4, 19, 5, 20, 21, 22, 10, 23, 11, 24, 12, 14, 25, 15, 17,
};
#endif
```

its suppose to be a cube where each face having a diff color,also each face is triangulated.  in the structure the x,y,x are the co ordinates on the axises, im not totally sure on the  nx,ny,nz but my best guess its the normals, and u v is possibily the colors (again, im not positive).

any ideas?

Comment: uv are the texcoords. But what is your question actually? If you want to render this with OpenGL, you'll need a lot more than the raw vertex data. You probably should look for some modern OpenGL tutorial.

Comment: yes, I would like to render it.
This is the way ill be tested although its outdated.

Comment: All the info is there, i think to get all the points the indicies have to be used some how.

Comment: I think answereing thins question in an adequate fashion would be out of the scope of this site - this would require writing half an OpenGL tutorial. OTOH, there are some good tutorials out there already, like [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/), [open.gl](http://open.gl) or [opengl-tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/). The short answer would be: create an OpenGL context, put your data into buffer objects, create a VAO and set your attribute pointers, write a vertex and a fragment shader, and issue the draw call. The linked tutorials will cover all that in great detail.